# Scholarship after competing with 1000 candidates around the world

Tags: traduction

How do we translate

> "Awarded scholarship XYZ after competing with 1000 candidates around
>   the world"

Would it be

> Lauréat de la bourse XYZ
>   attribuée après sélection de 1000 candidats au niveau mondial/après un concours avec 1000 candidats au niveau mondial

"après sélection de 1000 candidats" sounds like 1000 candidates are selected to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the sentence does not give information about the "winner" (you have translated it by "lauréat" which is correct) but only that the scholarship has been awarded. So the beginning would be "Bourse XYZ attribuée"

"après sélection de 1000 candidats" is not correct as you said because I think the candidates have already applied to intend the competition.

"niveau mondial" sounds a bit odd to me, it does not seem to be the correct translation for "around the world". You may rather think about an international competition.

I can suggest

> Bourse XYZ attribuée à l'issue d'un concours international impliquant 1000 candidats.

"à l'issue de" means "as a result" and "impliquant" would be "involving"

Answer (score 2):

"Sélection de 1 000 candidats" would indeed mean that 1000 candidates were selected, but "sélection parmi 1 000 candidats" would mean you were selected amongst the 1 000. Apart from that, there is no problem with what you proposed, but it could be improved a bit.

The translation of "competing" depends on the exact nature of the competition. "Concours" means "contest", so you had to do something specifically for the contest and were evaluated on... some criteria. For other forms or selection, based on your academic file or anything, it wouldn't fit. Without more context and details, the "one size fits all" answer could simply be "parmi", which just means "amongst".

"Lauréat" is a good fit but a bit pedantic; not enough to change it, but you might want to lighten the rest of the sentence a bit.
So a final version could be, depending on exactly how you got that scholarship :

> Lauréat de la bourse XYZ parmi 1 000 candidats au niveau mondial.
>
> Lauréat de la bourse XYZ à l'issue d'un concours impliquant 1 000 candidats du monde entier.
>
> Lauréat de la bourse XYZ après sélection sur dossier parmi 1 000 candidats dans le monde.

Or any mix of these. As @Coriolis pointed out, "concours international" would fit too.

Comment: I have seen _après selection_ on line in official documents _Ces points seront complétés par Audencia après sélection des dossiers_ https://apply.exchangestudents.audencia.com/index.cfm?FuseAction=Abroad.ViewLink&Parent_ID=334DE157-5056-BA1F-74D8BB5DBD9692BA&Link_ID=33563E8F-5056-BA1F-741940FC4C029019 and _TOTAL E&P Congo participera au ﬁnancement de 1 à 5 bourses d'études après sélection des dossiers et satisfaction des critères_. I had help written this phrase from a French friend some time ago who is good at writing. It is for line in CV

Comment: Yes, *après sélection* is fine. I was just pointing out that you need to be careful about *who* was selected: "*sélection de 1 000 candidats*" = 1000 candidates were selected, "*sélection parmi 1 000 candidats*" = there were 1 000 candidates and only a few, including you, were selected.

Comment: What I meant was in the example, _après sélection des dossiers_ not _après sélection PARMI des dossiers_, so analogous to my case would it be _après sélection 1000 candidats_ and without _parmi_ ?

Comment: @Kenny No, you can't. "après sélection des dossiers" means you had many candidates, and you select some of these. But here, you include the number of candidates, so you have to be very specifi to understand if it was the number of candidates or of selected candidaites. so "après selection parmi 1000 candidat" would be the correct form, but still odd. imo, the 2nd option given by DaWaaaaghBabal is the the most natural if it was a competition. If you only "asked" for it (without written exam or anything) you can't say "concours", so 3rd option would fit better...